# Firebase: Failed to verify the signature of Firebase ID token

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, flutter, firebase-authentication

When I try to verify the Firebase jwt token in my Spring Boot backend application, I get the following error:

> Failed to verify the signature of Firebase ID token. See
> https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for
> details on how to retrieve an ID token.

In the client (Flutter) I log the jwt as follows:

```
  GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
  );

  UserCredential authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  _user = authResult.user;

  logger.i(await _user.getIdToken()); // Print jwt
```

I send the jwt that gets logged to my backend through the Authorization header as a bearer token.

Using Spring security (it doesn't matter), I just perform the following check:

```
FirebaseToken decoded = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(token);
```

My firebase app init config is pretty standard (env variable pointing to config.json is set):

```
@Primary
@Bean
public void firebaseInit() throws IOException {
    FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault())
            .build();
    if (FirebaseApp.getApps().isEmpty()) {
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    }
}
```

After debugging, following method throws in class RSASignature (package package sun.security.rsa):

```
@Override
protected boolean engineVerify(byte[] sigBytes) throws SignatureException {
    if (publicKey == null) {
        throw new SignatureException("Missing public key");
    }
    try {
        if (sigBytes.length != RSACore.getByteLength(publicKey)) {
            throw new SignatureException("Signature length not correct: got " +
                sigBytes.length + " but was expecting " +
                RSACore.getByteLength(publicKey));
        }
```

sigBytes length is 113, whereas it expects to be 256.
Perhaps I'm doing something wrong though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My God... the logger that I used in dart decided to just cap the jwt string so the jwt was incomplete.
Now I get a message 'forbidden' happy joy. But the previous error has been resolved.

Edit 'Forbidden' was consequence of a minor Spring Boot issue (adding roles to authorities).
It now works as expected.

Comment: oh my god. thank you, I have no words.

Comment: Same sh" hahahhaha